# Laravel Database innerjoin primary key of the table does not display

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I cannot update using my javascript or in basic update because the id is the same.. Do you have any idea on how to resolve this? Please help...

How can I solve this, I have this in my controller

```
$dataReqorder = DB::table('reqorders')
            ->join('productquantities', 'reqorders.item_id', '=', 'productquantities.id')
            ->join('products', 'productquantities.prod_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->where('req_id', '=', $shoppingId)
            ->get();
            dd($dataReqorder);
```

And it has a result like this

```
Collection {#272 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#265 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"req_id": "ZJXYGX42RN"
      +"item_id": "1"
      +"quantity": 100
      +"amount": "6600"
      +"status": "0"
      +"remember_token": null
      +"created_at": "2018-03-10 15:18:38"
      +"updated_at": "2018-03-11 13:03:15"
      +"prod_id": 1
      +"brand_id": 1
      +"supplier_id": 1
      +"branch_id": 3
      +"category_id": "1"
      +"price": "200"
      +"saleprice": "100"
      +"priceoption": "regular"
      +"description": "brake for yamaha"
      +"lenght": "10"
      +"width": "10"
      +"height": "10"
      +"weight": "10"
      +"unit": "piece"
      +"pic": "1520752307.png"
      +"product_name": "Brake"
    }
    1 => {#286 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"req_id": "ZJXYGX42RN"
      +"item_id": "2"
      +"quantity": 100
      +"amount": "67000"
      +"status": "0"
      +"remember_token": null
      +"created_at": "2018-03-10 15:18:38"
      +"updated_at": "2018-03-11 13:03:15"
      +"prod_id": 1
      +"brand_id": 1
      +"supplier_id": 1
      +"branch_id": 3
      +"category_id": "1"
      +"price": "200"
      +"saleprice": "100"
      +"priceoption": "regular"
      +"description": "brake for yamaha"
      +"lenght": "10"
      +"width": "10"
      +"height": "10"
      +"weight": "10"
      +"unit": "piece"
      +"pic": "1520752614.png"
      +"product_name": "Brake"
    }
    2 => {#289 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"req_id": "ZJXYGX42RN"
      +"item_id": "4"
      +"quantity": 33
      +"amount": "1000"
      +"status": "0"
      +"remember_token": null
      +"created_at": "2018-03-10 15:18:38"
      +"updated_at": "2018-03-11 13:03:15"
      +"prod_id": 1
      +"brand_id": 1
      +"supplier_id": 1
      +"branch_id": 3
      +"category_id": "1"
      +"price": "2"
      +"saleprice": "2"
      +"priceoption": "regular"
      +"description": "brake for yamaha"
      +"lenght": "12"
      +"width": "2"
      +"height": "2"
      +"weight": "2"
      +"unit": "roll"
      +"pic": "1520752847.png"
      +"product_name": "Brake"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I cannot update using my javascript or in basic update because the id is the same.. Do you have any idea on how to resolve this? Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query selects all columns in all joined tables.
If multiple columns have the same name (e.g. `id`), the last one overwrites the previous ones.

You have to limit the selected columns and/or use aliases:

```
->get(['reqorders.*', 'products.id as products_id']);
```